# Canvas not sending image

Tags: javascript, node.js, html5-canvas, discord, discord.js

```
 const applyText = (canvas, text) => {
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');


    let fontSize = 70;

    do {
        ctx.font = `${fontSize -= 10}px sans-serif`;
    } while (ctx.measureText(text).width > canvas.width - 300);

    return ctx.font;
};


  client.on('guildMemberAdd', async member => {
    const channel = member.guild.channels.find(ch => ch.name === 'on-topic');
    if (!channel) return;

    const canvas = Canvas.createCanvas(700, 250);
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    const { body:buf } = await snekfetch.get('https://cdn.glitch.com/294c4c9f-8e20-4506-a23f-71a77d13c629%2Fimage.png?1541609757084');
    const background = await Canvas.loadImage(buffer);
    ctx.drawImage(background, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    ctx.strokeStyle = '#74037b';
    ctx.strokeRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    // Slightly smaller text placed above the member's display name
    ctx.font = '28px sans-serif';
    ctx.fillStyle = '#ffffff';
    ctx.fillText('Welcome to the server,', canvas.width / 2.5, canvas.height / 3.5);

    // Add an exclamation point here and below
    ctx.font = applyText(canvas, `${member.displayName}!`);
    ctx.fillStyle = '#ffffff';
    ctx.fillText(`${member.displayName}!`, canvas.width / 2.5, canvas.height / 1.8);

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(125, 125, 100, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.clip();

    const { body: buffer } = await snekfetch.get(member.user.displayAvatarURL);
    const avatar = await Canvas.loadImage(buffer);
    ctx.drawImage(avatar, 25, 25, 200, 200);

    const attachment = new Discord.Attachment(canvas.toBuffer(), 'welcome-image.png');

    channel.send(`Welcome to the server, ${member}!`, attachment);
});
```

I am receiving no errors but the image is not sending. I have the correct packages installed. If you would like more information, Just leave a comment and I'll be happy to add more! If anyone is willing to help it'd be greatly appreciated!

Thanks! :)

Comment: If you do `console.log(channel)` right before the return `if (!channel) return;`, do you get anything? It's possible that your code isn't finding the channel and returning incorrectly.

Comment: No, James, Nothing in the log if I do that @JamesIves

Comment: That sounds like that's the issue then, it's likely because the channel name cannot be found.

Comment: Changed it to this `  client.on('guildMemberAdd', async member => {
    let ont = '509761532293414936';
    let channel = message.guild.channels.get(ont)
    if (!channel) return;` But it still won't work